# Identify the Kaomoji!

Tags: code-challenge, classification

### Background

This is loosely based on the now closed [Kaomoji question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/219146/typing-faces-with-programming) asked a few hours ago.

Kaomojis are sequences of characters designed to express a given emotion. In this [code-challenge](/questions/tagged/code-challenge), you'll be writing a program that takes a Kaomoji as input, and must output the emotion expressed by the Kaomoji.

### Input

A Kaomoji. In this challenge, there are 13 categories of emotions the kaomojis can express:

1. [Joy](https://pastebin.com/hPAFsCi7)
2. [Love](https://pastebin.com/rjJ0nL2P)
3. [Embarrassment](https://pastebin.com/LKSbAXuH)
4. [Sympathy](https://pastebin.com/eMwsPD1s)
5. [Dissatisfaction](https://pastebin.com/dc89LMe9)
6. [Anger](https://pastebin.com/CKkv3Ace)
7. [Sadness](https://pastebin.com/0N3g4q5S)
8. [Pain](https://pastebin.com/bhHjjh0Y)
9. [Fear](https://pastebin.com/7Mf1MDhd)
10. [Indifference](https://pastebin.com/8yEcLmjt)
11. [Confusion](https://pastebin.com/mJJqA8N7)
12. [Doubt](https://pastebin.com/Xy0bCXex)
13. [Surprise](https://pastebin.com/vH0Wg9nc)

You will be given one kaomoji from any of these lists as input. [This link](http://kaomoji.ru/en/) contains all of the kaomojis in this challenge. Here's a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/tpje7V2k) version.

### Output

Your program should output the emotion expressed by the kaomoji. You can express this as an integer (i.e., Joy = 1, Love = 2, etc), or output a string containing the emotion.

### Scoring

Your score is (B+1)*exp(3W/(360-W)), where B is the number of bytes in your program, and W is the number of kaomojis that your program incorrectly categorizes. Lowest score wins!

Comment: OK I am not that much creative, for making a powershell answer can I scrape the raw paste data from the pastebin pages?

Comment: Can you please make the post self-contained without all those links? They all give me 502 errors anyway.

Comment: @Noodle9 It is self-contained. Everything you need is in the paste-bin links.

Comment: That's the opposite of self-contained! T_T Self-contained means all the info is in the actual post, **not** links to the info.

Comment: @Noodle9 pastebins are considered to be self-contained. This challenge is impossible to be self-contained since there are more characters than are allowed in a question body.

Comment: @Noodle9 (and anyone having trouble accessing pastebin) You can copy the full list from the input section of the "test all kaomojis" TIO link in my answer. Groups are separated by "\n\n".

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), Score 643

#### <s>656 651 646</s>  642 bytes, no error

Returns an integer from **1** to **13**.

```javascript
s=>`qv%s!u.r0vPyqv*s"r'yqyu@y2r%{ }1u!v(u{y8|!ru;rur&z+z,w'z-{){{0x'r*z/{Py$t w#z,xFt,}qzr.{#s$t%vv6{@s&v z$x@{!{6v,sCr6s<v z.r s*w=w,r0u5s r){,y!s-s%v8t.xrqyWr7r?z#uBz9r&v#v5yBw+w"})vNw-u4sz)y"zEu/z r"}/rqw w\\t0|(r*rw(uAw&v {uYw#x wqz*|)v2u/|'v!r#sBs}0w&r2y&s r%r6w+}){"r2{-usqw'}C|/v$y={!r!x!t/rt>r1r"svuCy*{qr>v1x2r6x#{5{.wv8wGwqr!r:vJ|#r#u%uqst-}'r"z\`zqw uHy$sYr-z0w#|3{8x7vqz.w!|Ez$uvw!z.{t'w+{5x&|.xmrt"s,u"vuqwy{$t5u&s'wAv"vsTw#z%u*z0s r/w v#}+w'r9}0r0|AvxHv,r*}qw:x r3w}!u0v(w{qvv"y.rSr0w4yr#r.}qw"}%s"v#r!w!u/| tCs u`.replace(/[ -p]/g,c=>"q".repeat(c[C='charCodeAt']()-30))[C]([...s].map((c,i)=>s^=c[C]()<<i%5)|s%8788*3672%4051)%56
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZJhaxxFGMff@ylmd29vd/Z25zaX3OVac2eSo1p8IQUFKUm8HOe1RtIm@8zOzO7MLhQKrYUg2sY7C6KNRaTv@kojXBpoP4C@Fd@EzQe4j5DOiajI@mKeGf7zY57/82c@HfABHcLOfhzc3vt4dHGjc0E73e2I29RgBEJ@LY24R01w0ihlq2kDbIXyBWZwl6m0nRnA3gQGVVmTvnBkoLBSYeKAJ@vqWlqJkbCkn7wd@3kkgSiLVmKb85ZapVWOZCVZVYZqcZ/2oEVXtEIAUU90hA8ha1IEWPmpQQNq83ZMEojSD2EZ3pIWW5eXoMot3kzXRU2YOebviYAtUYlTU15hdYnAzOsQCSQ2N@Mwc8ED4bI1ofsqdl1YCRKR9DLMG6yeOdwAi67TPBRVaKRV3dmGlqjlWJnQUAGjkXDyXlbnlbSjDDASI65D3IUFMClnvdRTEXT5QtKAVmKppiKCt8U7IgIDLvN3MwssZrOIxkHugCk3t6U2xq6mFXodAhkKK1tU7WSZR5III7siK4wLQxIVO6Kmmkk1I8ktiE3qM5OzSKSqEjdZlTpijZucfqBDtpknQ227LhC38ppw4FIeQpit8eQq98HLI3E5QbAocoOF3BUq4txMCbwPoVhKwQKiCTO3qcktMIShQ0FxjyK2TWC0vzsYjtz6Bgr2t@o3/WGna0bmXB8NYne40es4w08G0NMfaC12tlwcLIYYb/S23A1CCN0itwb7rjv0d3CnSz/qDOc3eGVlx27ijNrt5XbbW2wtN@ylsLmA7WbrYrh3m@7tjsju3k33hmv@/swtJl8Vd051nZ0c4T9@MjF@4z@QWzw@evm8GJ/o8vgIlxFnx/fR2fHPxfh0vuGz4x9LKN1gdvLD7MV3urqzFw9@O9zG53dP3Nnp018f6ILKnl6ZX6PZLwdI77hbQhSHB8Vnz4rDL/QoT/vF5Hv8t1JCk39c/GVk@m1/Nv0G/1vUDCkb89Wk/2qCi4OHxdf3ypyMHxXjh8X4S1cnNdGZYX3@U3lUQs9HP7877euFdA6flzWcTZ9oc09KMy/uTft64f95@uXz8zv3tQUdtCYuXgM)

Or [test all kaomojis](https://tio.run/##bVjtcxPHGf@uv2It2@j2kE4GAqF@UUJokr5N6UyY6XQwOhFDErfUQqeXsySLOduJsRISwLEsU4yDATtJB2IlyOAQycyIT40Zy9NpO5PpF/vUTmfaD/oT0t@zeyeLtDO@1e6z@7zs877@7ZnUmfiQMXwhERiJnj33/VsD38cHQpFYqjvekdSMntSv0rGUGvcavnQsnXw5fdDozrLcgWRHSklm00fHOoxkn5E09mX2Z/ymLxPI8my2Z9RnqJlg9lfprgQzOzP@0dcS/lwsY2jZznhXojuVOpJ9Ob4vxTJdoy9nO7JHUv74ceNIvB8QzWBx1Rww/UZP8nCcGTzrT3fEA/Hu1NGENmrE0r82XjReynQmX8n8yNiX6kwdTr9i7je9OZ76pRlIvhDP8LQ382oymGGGNxc0YiYzBwcTPWOKoRqmkjxmgm82@Ruzc5SZsYw6xlMHk8ExX6rD6Iy/Es/1mPuMg@l94NxtHDH353jWaxzMBpLxmOnLHR8LprrSA9kOo2O0IxE0EiHjgOGNp5LH02o2ZoRSB0YPGkdGO7OHs5qZOmq@bsaMDqM39bOxTqMz2Z2MxROBnM/wZgYjGQiW/Em6K/4bI5DpMTvHDmWPjr6YimU0s2Ps1UxXMmV2ZLRswmfuzx4e3Temjf7eSHjj/qQ3lYyZ6WxX4nByX9xnHkt5U/GTUHJ3Us30QOygyVKduf2mz/hRrsfoGTuWGv1Jym@ouZjZO8qMQ2auI9mTUsxsLJXypjXjDaPHfCFtdBoaTnhz3XFvqtPoMDugFJY4HmfJiGacu3D@zNA5JXiKBS6cDr7tHxoIeWNegp87k1CGTh0f8A29c8Y4Dgc6lvCdVnjgUA/np46fVk5pmhY/rf3@zAVFGfIP84FQPDwwRDu8v3@4@zAfi3cfffHoUfXQkRcPdr/Qc/gA7z585HvjXCw5bJxTfG/FfRx8zpx9bfj8uTfSI0NKD9cS0TcSxvDI2wrX4hfODycU7@DI4IiXa29FjVfPDL2jKG8b0eQFPxs@y9lAiGU9jA1FR@LR8@e089G3lcjrtM26svv3D5/N9Q6OdGUFwh410CKR44StRH/H9g0wxWAD7C0lzkFyAJT98E0/w94AO8C130aHRxQv8/IcO9WVBfQl5jvxcx/rZb7Xjv30F6/@2Jc7PTgS4X2eHP9eUVmY1fMszD1KrczsaYtFmMo9332u2MWCbT3B2Kwu8b8/9NjzU2qvhoUWVez8p/Zc1c6v8KiA9KrY9SjRMKDhKGjZl2fowOUZThv9SvPJneb6Q4w85GlYE1qvoNasLvsUlc5aBYwq59zTmKwqjclvIAlG3tzIk2DgYVu3SVD8YBEBCxCr54mip1m1@nobEzf6aAKaSq20tVYrMRyKYolT1WUSqlm51axs2MUljJKRCh71fItRVGc6zf4JdnSf8D8ePybNRGtl3CZCNFQ5VYnrUnPjE4VhCEPaMH6B@wnAHoVBlxA2QiIoShRYJWDVSiqP0h2F/opLpD9JfNoSxDFr3VJcEdLOVYW0pNF6nhTqsaevncUVgVQrncWyUFLsuVksMXK7sIqzsxaZDn@zFskcxjSsyitHwwwWEte1F1ZJioVVIu9am85DPPDKr6i0MT9FlpyfcqyKQyREs1Jp84Jm5Yok3pI4yhuTH5HPsGZ1UfGRX0CZQoGuKsjJpGGfjQtxbz@zHF@DaCTBwqeOmVrupP7AI3bXCm0uQWrHOal3uAaJQg5CKoLh4IEwHGmIiIagsX66Fwn6nEuLS4O9uHNj/M7mfD2Pb4LJa@8RpmuD8CoI11ZVZ7dlM9ptjyNxsejmPHS@OQ9zD4LNe8TmPR7EItyY/CKMmdKwJltEMCe9F1ahCxIPGiH5o0qonu@HpFGF2Tdv7JaLGBnWjlOeBK2Te95oWxvPxhn4OjPSzka@VsapCClU7YWVlnHco7wJlc6CE0b@pkfZ@fra5iTIb07w5jf35Xoe192cx4w0vnn93zMPbOuDzetEVf33zMrO4zJAYrLGPbXS5hzJXryp2OOw/BOM3C4uALY5VytJUy6DA0bHbht5KAuikcqEcFI2YEAT1iKZ/W/vk9WxwHmNrg4CpAiNlDVu7RZvYyR59mz1phAWAkhJa6uY1sjzGRlojgzk2Pe7ZSCTssctJozoaIttP2IR4S2KfX1pq6JvVURwIbKwJl@Hgwp39TWrdwEdeicpjgb0AEbpkltrlAort6RjA0y@gU1BlrkpmJaIG0Z0n49mAfm/7i8Pq0QSqUDyqy4htwWDW2vBICYUXCLNU2oSJzDQ/YUQ8I7n8oAgFxRuWEHYVZeidvEDAdydXIEXX0ZcYMbFFZ2gbhHF8QCxCYjlD3PA83mOOXdiW2vkAc/fsC3ly3NtMU6lp1m9IpT/gwiXunBcVeVukRLqvL60eZ3g111p/yeo5blWjnbMsFfSBPHaKqs9oLAXS5Emth8pjmKYRKK7E2iuujkf@st78EC5LSLHmZK6WljQeDgQVpCjVR4UJCiDwNvWSFgkkPokCYZlfqU@2cbEvmSxQ8yeqkiF0322iyL5KfbNu8gyN@9iCj7TFngGla0KzAwHRtTc9eBjyp9mN6foAlMkytSQNJPrn5RdYd7ikmPjrTsh1GxKVbVSPV8rUZ6iw1MzhOb3w2bgad32@117IidExFxoUsfXR8VPVCNoM4gqXRHxFER/4E51Z4L4w/5GnjAQTQLDDcA2/6V6hcSlUfKSWFRZCRokRw4GxayeFxOEWFstQhxrYdXFgicIZi2vUHljYpFyy7sMH@We8XdxQXdKQCGwGy6toyHxC3/Fb//eSaSuna@W6nkMMovtrF9iO@uPkIjoh@@sI9kxaBWosgaA9BOQhosI0fV@qAlpYkNpq3kiHpZF2l@mnLU9S5mk2mqVcKQ@rsjAbFjjAt3d62MyJblr2HYCfwwXvynaHvZTJooF1RdBG91WW89DuBf1i9S76fgcPByEDW@0BBX9JW7TRzKApYQLKzHZXTUmK8SF7rhdFm5XDtTzgYjC0JwxWZBr5XpeyILKiPYOg0h2VxzelD1t66arpnFSWbOCorrYrCyItuoGfPyZpdOIXWRuICtyn6RFohO2Z/jGxsYkCkXUrIwo4RZLGBvWh1zSfnKnx9kTC6czxcnbOr4@sbHYrH4oJQAeYmbyfq3EMXVKPrjDwgt90t4o/uJPzNE6r3/dXH8seTcm5wX1finj15eZbKxll/3ElWOx@fUVyS6AmEEm/uel9XZ00j1hnqBVY/JdDyUR21pHErGth5yajH7qKUhaR3dC2N3izG7xzi5KxF8REv@ZntbxOTqObM/WyuAY@dcfniAdC@lhcRgb1pcOxiLb5VpZlRUP1orURSfyDWHB@IROxyLIEASXpZFEj9hzD/ZoosMnivVpom9PXxIM6tPiVqAzDzrCWRdlobXWoA3ABNfmxkwEffsNJmS1C/ci/7rxPs3t2cv29Of27FXUwTu6XbzNWxAhAnPRGMcSWRCddwWugJEkpRzZeG8CWaVwT4hG8PF1ZxdFUORHiFArEcOSlObPE1DJI3EbyEm0sImR01ZLTuKnkKyQDFch2eQzrXDv23kgfDtPTEXvXLjHns7gzNOPRUODP5xDvxYJ18rUtv39IWqc6F1BdOerW8DGKDjYU9d0ZWvF3FrhW59hdfWisvUZZGlWSySRPT3t2bn/qaJ0bq0Aa2ulk/Od@5@RHDslQad0S8gA1e98tSwIL4uWvS1pwR/1wF5gc4/mJC0nb1WuyFrQDtU8ipvvnbwGKsAW0U2ZamIBf9Q2VFbRKcgl4HBi9MLzJ6liMDfpiMYITUJzfQ19g@iK9jLnxieqEtou93O1xVw20TSvXNaR1pD4QOMf63/U8cn2XJLytxGCnJ@E@lsJ0iHi5ism0XQgidmyLpKY1i6HVMaiToHXDqRehoLtyuaHCBuhgbZUR8TIP4ic8xoQP3l651bpsu6zoDGOviAim0KMJ0k7J52lqLfE6i5RaZWU6hK9OwQRF@hRTuongRLS@93X0rPP7cJ9u/AFzTggjhzU4SshyNbPmYu@BAM1LHJWjJRr3Ach8ljrQYjq@BXdiXzJ47lIrC5yp99WQqgK/Xsr2Lxfvlr1l/H7tKg/LeJ3VB9traiRo9c9wdz50yLFS1HQoTz2tCjQmpUPoP4PuOcUq30JRhhOk7M/LTLsw9H1XvjcTtWKIDMiC93ivbp0daFtQeFKq5@hYiigmkaGQ6ISWzKzTjyi6H@AotCYuEEVsq9P1VVh2m/QNYsESY1qw7qko1rJt2era3I6pYa1oLRS9QLlJ@pwHtRKVMWa62X6b4Szj@yRzTJhNpbLCdK1x@gklhh@zo@dx0u0Yd1Bu/14axYQ0Lvjsec@tufQBV9ze0GOuYB87HH@cVPBDStMJDYCiHpOTf3sZY9Iq9Y80qADEBiWRYW1LGvQR@LQXo1yT1Fhqy6KgmvJY4UvCKiLQ4X74tDmJWBtXmonI5Fa3FFHqUFbfyghkoZ7BlRqq4M67vAu14O1VYFBqX67zNwbEAbV4ieCBjAcPmhg2vmgt4eH36WfdjyXN@EB8twphxYWejtWa73HCy9jl9duoaCw3at4@e8Wip69f4mh3cA7QahrXIyTsnGQV@2TGbiPCyekP0HaR4bpE3TdJg4uKnsThy6m1AY/Z6PnMfokI12as0VeatqRje6C9zfTWG1VNka3dPEiVuTxPtFrw3cFxwmSWzTjchcvq5coUm7vrJd1@cMJUPwID4GPZJsOn8MfaO9O/gG545aOj2EuAbVV6rxWvQLgCvLdspzLWatxo1QyhdfK1Ixs5piEYcSTg9aEdU@v3RMJfeoqTl4VICZBtXs45@5WdPE@ozZLx0ePlY8thg8MTYQUwhohZcrAwZPqElZUO6GKE/oJLsNZdo0g8v51HR@9iGiPTpAyT2gnZBsijrEOuU2/CG0dH5ddizO3p6@5mKyX7Xy5gtf2uvjtZfy/).

#### How?

The input string is turned into an integer **N** with:

```javascript
[...s].reduce((p, c, i) => p ^ c.charCodeAt() << i % 5, 0)
```

(using `.map()` instead of `.reduce()` in the golfed code)

Example for `٩(◕‿◕｡)۶`:

```
 code | << |  shifted bit-mask
------+----+--------------------
 1641 |  0 |        11001101001
   40 |  1 |            101000.
 9685 |  2 |   10010111010101..
 8255 |  3 |  10000000111111...
 9685 |  4 | 10010111010101....
65377 |  0 |   1111111101100001
   41 |  1 |            101001.
 1782 |  2 |      11011110110..
------+----+--------------------
       XOR = 110010100100101110 = 207150
```

In the lookup string:

- The emotions are encoded as `'q'` to `'}'` (ASCII codes 113 to 125).
- The characters `' '` to `'p'` (ASCII codes 32 to 112) encode a run of consecutive `'q'` (which, in addition to 'joy', also depicts an unused slot). The length of such a run is `ord(c) - 30` (minimum = 2, maximum = 82).

We first [expand the lookup string](https://tio.run/##bVLLThsxFN3zFbYnk3lkXgQSAjSUENGiLiokKlWoVCIKI2iVJvG1fe/Ynvn2dFh01@2956Wj83uFK7WGX3udb3cv9eHwwObsWWKouCmgwnsrMVUCIiutubZjCD3rjg3H2Hg7azmYSzAwdCOXUeRyn3hfNRGkrvT3dqAZBS5rPumskw4KH6iBDhGn/loNkblBc@25n2KmljBVH/pLAUylNKcMKjNRDBKfWa5yFeJMFw1I@x3O4KMLzI07hyEGOLE3NCLRJfiVcnOqXGKFuzWlYyC6EiQxenrSVRtDChSbBfW@3jxS0DCSLm0THJuyjZBDoG5UV9EQxnbYO4cwpVGXeAFjnxslKeqWbYkDO/cceMN1CfoKjkEoNEubeglXeNyMYdoEfuILwhl9JgkcLvBLG0BgQiOVzrsIhHt6dn0wc2cH6hFyV1HQnvhZc4bSFcTbWzcwSNwVXkc08pNm2BbNH9BCZUagkWT9QE/MUEW0QIHqW19yaFJX9bFLYhh0I4rgvKugahfY3GEGaSfpomFwQh03FcbkJaKwBTxARacWAih6hOhCJTAATrwvhemlYub58uiobvar7Uv90k/joYB6v1mt67j8wfL9z/I1Y2s2v2JCivdXvdLxuli/rWDZz2mh44Tl7KRKkl5mvduq3aYuNrvX@J9ksam3r/qNjZhg76zVWtegRA//Hzq5PBz@Ag) to 4048 characters by replacing `/[ -p]/g` with the runs of `'q'` and then extract the relevant character with the following hash formula, which was found by brute-forcing some random values during a few minutes:

```
N % 8788 * 3672 % 4051
```

The final answer is the ASCII code of the character modulo 56.

Comment: I discovered that, i you could allow 3 or 4 incorrect results, and reduce your code size to 600 bytes, you'll get a score approximately 650 (< 652).

Comment: @SketchySketch Unfortunately, removing 50 bytes with my current method would probably result in ~25 errors (rough estimation).